# phpmyadmin domain name

Tags: apache, tomcat, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I have setup an Ubuntu LAMP server, and I have had phpmyadmin working fine with my website. However, I have recently had to create a virtual host for my IP address to avoid a security issue with directory listings in Tomcat, and now I can no longer access phpmyadmin.

It used to be at 192.68.1.99/phpmyadmin, and the actual phpmyadmin files are located in

```
 /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

I have a domain name pointing at my sever which I can use to point at phpmyadmin - how do I configure this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

To your global configuration or to virtual host which serves 192.68.1.99:80

This will allows you to access it again on URL http://192.68.1.99/phpmyadmin

If you want to setup phpmyadmin to be available using domain name, it is very same,
just put this line into VirtualHost settings of server under which you want to access it.

If you receive errors like **access forbidden**, add also following lines:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Allow from all
    Deny from None
    Order Allow,Deny
</Directory>

<Location /phpmyadmin>
    Allow from all
    Deny from None
    Order Allow,Deny
</Location>
```

Comment: Hi rkosegi, thanks for your help once again! I have added all 3 lines above to my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file, but this has made no difference. It seems that these config files don't seem to do anything? Could this be the case?

Comment: rkosegi, the alias (Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin) in my /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.co.uk file only has any effect if I disable the site, using a2dissite mysite.co.uk - does that give you any clues as to whats going on? thanks

Comment: @Christy Herron, I can not give you answer without more info.I need related parts of apache config file.

Comment: my apache2.conf file contains the 'Alias ...' line. This doesn't have any effect on sites which are enabled. It does have an effect on sites which have been disabled. It's as if the config files are being ignored, and therefore the configuration for these sites must be being managed elsewhere? Maybe somewhere in Tomcat?

Comment: I still haven't found a solution to this problem. What specifically do you need me to post? thanks @rkosegi